# ef core one to many relationship throw exception Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

My Shop and Product entities have a one to many relationship, please see my models

```
public class Product
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Tag { get; set; }
   public string Brand { get; set; }
   public string Place { get; set; }

   public int ShopID { get; set; }
   public Shop Shop { get; set; }
}

public class Shop
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}



 public class ShopContext : DbContext
    {
        public ShopContext(DbContextOptions<ShopContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>().ToTable("shop");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("product");
        }

    }

public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ShopContext _context;

    public CreateModel(ShopContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["Shop"] = new SelectList(_context.Shops, "ID", "Name");

        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Products.Add(Product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

The shop in create page is a dropdown list, when I post the new product to the handler, I can see the product.ShopID is an ID which exist in Shop table, and the product.Shop.ID as same as the product.ShopID. But when I call saveChangesAsync(), it throws an exception:

MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shopdb`.`product`, CONSTRAINT `FK_product_shop_ShopID` FOREIGN KEY (`ShopID`) REFERENCES `shop` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

I tried to set product.Shop to null before call saveChangesAsync method, but still doesn't work, anyone can help?

ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages Application,
Nuget: Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v2.0.1

Comment: Check `Product` table also whether it has a record with `ID` 1. Or Check if records are not inserted twice

Comment: @viveknuna thanks for your reply, please check my updated question, I tried again, and it throws an exception like that

Comment: make the `ShopID` nullable in `Product` table. then add-migration and then `update-database`

Comment: Not totally necessary to configure one-to-many tables in modelBuilder since it will do that for your automatically.  Also, it's recommended that you rename your ID properties to YourTableNameID, like ShopID instead of ID.

Comment: @viveknuna works well, thanks! but why I have to define ShopID as nullable int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `ShopID` as nullable in the `Product` table, you are doing `product.Shop = null;`, so it tries to insert `ShopID` value `null` in this column. Since you column `ShopID` in `Product` table is not nullable, that is why its giving error. Because there is no `Id` in `Shop` table which is nullable. So its giving  **foreign key constraint fails** exception. So all you have to do is to make use the nullable foreign key like `public int? ShopID`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't make `ShopID` nullable if it's required by design.

The problem you are experiencing is because `Add` method also recursively marks all entity instances reachable through navigation properties and not currently tracked by the context as `Added` (i.e. new).

It can be solved in many ways:

- Setting entity entry to `Added` instead of `Add` method:

  ```
  _context.Entry(Product).State = EntityState.Added;
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  ```
- Setting the navigation property to `null` **before** calling `Add`:

  ```
  Product.Shop = null;
  _context.Products.Add(Product);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  ```
- Attaching the navigation property object **before** calling `Add`:

  ```
  if (Product.Shop != null) _context.Attach(Product.Shop);
  _context.Products.Add(Product);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  ```
- Using `Update` instead of `Add`:

  ```
  _context.Products.Update(Product);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  ```

The last technique is explained in [Saving Data - Disconnected Entities - Mix of new and existing entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#mix-of-new-and-existing-entities):

> With auto-generated keys, Update can again be used for both inserts and updates, even if the graph contains a mix of entities that require inserting and those that require updating

Since it works only when all entities use auto-generated PKs, and also produces unnecessary updates of the related entities, I don't recommend it.