# EF trying to create new entry instead of relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a `User` model, and a `UserRole` model. In the database, UserRole is an enumerator (visualized below). When I initialized the database, the Users table has a column UserRoleId, so I assumed that Entity Framework made the relation correctly.

However, when I try to add a user, I get an error that EF is trying to create a new entry in the `UserRole` table.

I don't want it to create a new entry in the `UserRole` table, I want a number to be inserted into the `UserRoleId` column of the User table that references to a Role within the `UserRole` table.

**Error:**

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Error: Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32), @p1='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SET NOCOUNT ON;
>   INSERT INTO [UserRoles] ([Id], [Role]) 
>   VALUES (@p0, @p1);
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserRoles' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

**UserRoles Table in DB:**

```
ID  |  Role
==============
1   |  Viewer
2   |  Owner
3   |  Admin
```

**Models:**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }  //<--- THE IMPORTANT PART
    ...
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add how you are creating the entries. Also, you should always be explicit and add a `public int UserRoleId { get; set; }` in your User class

Comment: Pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889676/ef-core-one-to-many-relationship-throw-exception-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-ro - see my answer there (all options except #3 (setting navigation property to `null`) because your model has no explicit FK property)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, edited to add more detail

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Explicitly adding the UserRoleId to the User model, then changing the DTOs and front end to reflect that change worked.

Comment: You should add that as answer then. I would remove the Angular stuff from the question though as it is not too relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Camilo Terevinto pointed out, it's necessary to explicitly add UserRoleId to the User model. After that, `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`, and alter the front end, the controller, and the DTO so that UserRoleId is being passed in instead of a UserRole object.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public int UserRoleId { get; set; } //<--- THE IMPORTANT PARTS
    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }  //<--- THE IMPORTANT PARTS
    ...
}
```