# Reuse record in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have experienced a problem where EF is trying to double insert a record of the same model instance. More details below.

Data models:

```
public class PostDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public AccountDataModel Author { get; set; }
}

public class AccountDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

So first, I do create an account and store it:

```
var account = new AccountDataModel() {
    Login = "Test",
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith"
};

// Store new account
_dbContext.Accounts.Add(account);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then, I want to store the post and use the same account model instance for the author property in my `PostDataModel`.

```
// Store post
_dbContext.Posts.Add(new PostDataModel() {
    Content = "Lorem ipsum dolor...",
    Author = account // Here is my problem
});

_dbContext.SaveChanges(); // 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Accounts.Id'.
```

My problem is that, when post is being stored with `Author` property being the same `account` instance I used to store the account, then EF is trying to store my account twice (and since I do have an unique constraint set, it throws an error).

Why is that? How can I properly link a post author to `AccountDataModel` instance that is previously stored?

Comment: When you save the account, what is the ID that is stored? Is your entity configuration set up to recognize db-generated identity values?

Comment: @StevePy Id is a primary key with auto increment. In case of mine and this fresh setup, it is set to 1 for a new account. What do you mean by that `Is your entity configuration set up to recognize db-generated identity values`?

Comment: @Rusco, you have to add `AccountId` to class declaration and assign that property instead of whole `Author`: `AccountId = account.Id`

Comment: @Rusco: With code-first and SQL Server, this should be handled automatically and if it's inserting "1" for the new account then that appears to be working. For your 2 pieces of code, storing the account and then the post, are these occurring within the same method? Is _dbContext in the post call the exact same reference of the context used to create the account, or was account passed into a different method where _dbContext was recreated?

Comment: Make sure `account` is attached to the `_dbContext` before calling `Add` of the related entity. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889676/ef-core-one-to-many-relationship-throw-exception-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-ro/50906962#50906962

Comment: @IvanStoev It is. When I change it's state to unchanged, then it works fine.

Comment: Is this a web application (disconnected) or a connected (desktop) app?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do this instead :

```
_dbContext.Posts.Add(new PostDataModel() {
    Content = "Lorem ipsum dolor...",
    Author = new AccountDataModel() {
    Login = "Test",
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith"
}});

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: No. What if author is already stored in the database? This will store a new one. I don't want that. What I want is when I specify the `Author`, it should use existing  instead of creating a new one.

Comment: In that case looks something wrong with modeling. Your PostDataModel should have Author ID I believe.

Comment: It has. `AccountId` is a shadow property created automatically by EF.